# Prove $A_n = (-1, n)$ is an open cover of $[0, \infty)$. How can I guarantee $(-1, n), (-1, n+1), ...$ eventually encompasses $[0, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

I have to prove $A_n = (-1, n)$ is an open cover of $[0, \infty)$. Clearly here the archimedean property allows me to always find an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ bigger than any other I might choose, so we could make $\mathscr{F} = \{(-1, n), (-1, n+1), ...\}$ tend to infinity so that we can take its union to get something like (this is the step I don't know how to do) $\cup\mathscr{F} = \{ (-1, \infty)\}$. But how do I argue that not only it tends to infinity, but that it actually encompasses $[0, \infty)$, so that $[0, \infty) \subset \cup\{(-1, n), (-1, n+1), ... \}$, so that it's union actually does resolve in the way I mentioned?

That is, how do I prove $\cup\mathscr{F} = \{ (-1, \infty) \}$, so that I can say $[0, \infty) \subset \cup\mathscr{F}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $[0,\infty)=\{x\in\Bbb R:x\ge0\}$. Clearly $0\in(-1,1)$. Let $x>0$. Then by Archimedean property, we can find an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $1/n<1/x$, i.e. $n>x$. Thus $x\in(-1,n)\implies x\in\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}(-1,n)$.

Comment: Thank you for the proof, it is highly appreciated! However, I'm a bit lost on how to interpret it, sorry... I'm new to the subject. Why is it that you propose $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{x}$ before concluding to $n > x$?

Comment: @shintuku I was using another version of the Archimedean property. The answer to your question is basically this: to show $[0,\infty)\in\cup\mathscr F$, just show that $x>0\implies x\in\mathscr F$ for some $\mathscr F$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Following your advice, would the following work? Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the collection of all sets $A_n = (-1, n)$. Notice $[0, \infty) = \{ r \in \mathbb{R}: r \geq 0 \}$. Let $x \in \{ r \in \mathbb{R}: r \geq 0 \}$. Then, by the Archimedean property, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 \leq x < n$, and therefore, $\exists A_s = (-1, s)$, where $s \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $x \in A_s$. Therefore, for any $x \geq 0$, $x$ is in some $A_s$, and therefore $[0, \infty) \subset \cup\{(-1,n), (-1, n+1), ...\}$ .

Comment: @shintuku Yes, that is the way to go.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thank you so much for your help!!